# Creating Drag and Drop Inventory in Java

Tags: java, swing

In my AP Computer Science class we are working on a capstone project, and I decided to create an AGUI to facilitate a small text based video game. On of the components I would like to implement is an inventory/character equipment menu. I have started by created a Sprite class that has a HashMap of item attributes and an Image of it, but how should I go about displaying them in a grid-like inventory box? And then how could I drag and drop them between boxes? Should it all be one JPanel with constraints on where items can be placed, or individual JPanel objects for each slot?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to do this. However, for example in my game I'm working on currently I have a base position for each slot, an itemId that corresponds to which image to render, and a int quantity for each slot. When switching slots for example I just transfer the 3 values.

Comment: I'd use two lists each with an appropriate renderer for displaying the `Sprite` entries. *"And then.."* ..ask another, single, specific question. SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk.

Comment: I can think of at least three ways you might be able to achieve, which one you might use will depend on how you've implemented project and how much functionality you really want